# MAMP Joomla not using CSS

Tags: css, windows, joomla, mamp

I've set up a MAMP local server to test a website and make a template. The problem is however, the localhost is not using the CSS I provided. It's in the Head, there is no console error, and I can open it with opening the provided link in the head, only the CSS styles aren't being used. I tried every browser available so I can guess this is something to do with MAMP. I've used my local IP to see if that made any difference, but it didn't.

It is driving me nuts, can someone help me out?

Comment: Have you checked the link tag corresponds to <link  rel="stylesheet" href="//ur file path"> to file you want to class it in

Comment: Yes, I've checked that all. I can even open the file if I use the Google Dev tool (firebug like tool) it displays nice in my browser. I don't understand it, AT ALL.

Comment: What's the path to CSS file?

Comment: Is ur mamp server running ur html file without any css styles